# Problem while including html file in a div with Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

For a project i must include an HTML file into a div. This HTML file contains a menu that will be displayed on each page of the website. (To make it easier to edit the menu if we need to add something in it)

I include this file in my div with jQuery (.load). It works correctly on Firefox and IE. The menu displays well and I can click on the "parents" to show children.

But with Chrome, when I click the parent, the page refresh. It doesn't do anything else that refreshing the page without showing the children. (Sometimes when we spam click the menu, it opens, I don't know why and how)

But when I paste the code for the menu directly in my main HTML file, the menu works fine on all browsers.

Did you have any idea of why my menu doesn't want to work when it's included and used with Chrome ?

The include in my main html :

```
<div id="menuLeftLoad"></div>
<script>
$("#menuLeftLoad").load("Menuleft.html");
</script>
```

Here is the MenuLeft.html file :

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li class="parent"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> <span>Tables</span></a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li id="basic-tables"><a href="basic-tables.html">Basic Tables</a></li>
      <li id="data-tables"><a href="data-tables.html">Data Tables</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is a link to see this problem in real: http://allanresin2.tk/testui/index.html

**EDIT (Solution) :**

The solution has been founded by @CarstenLøvboAndersen .

I had a JS file (custom.js) that acted on my menu before everything else, so it caused problems when i wanted to click in the menu.

So, i replaced this :

```
jQuery('.leftpanel .nav .parent > a').click(function()
```

With this :

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.leftpanel .nav .parent > a',function()
```

So now, we have this function that wait for my click to execute. Before, the function was executed while the menu had not even finished loading.

Thanks to all people that tried to help me

Comment: working fine for me. Can you tell the chrome version?

Comment: I'm not fully sure I understand the problem, but try using `<a href="#">` instead

Comment: I believe the problem is that your click function exist in the `custom.js` file, and that file is loaded before your `$("#menuLeftLoad").load("Menuleft.html");`, so to make it work try replace `jQuery('.leftpanel .nav .parent > a').click(function()` with `jQuery(document).on('click','.leftpanel .nav .parent > a',function()`

Comment: @The_ehT curious, i have Chrome 78.0.3904.97

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i tried this, and the menu doesn't open, but at least, the page stopped reload at each click

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I just tried this and now it works ! I understand now why i was having this issue, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see in your code, there is no click event for the a tags.
So what you need is a click handler, that prevents the default behaviour of the a tag and loads the html file instead. 
Here you have some dummy code:

main.html:

```
<main>
 <h1>Hi i am main</h1>
 <a class="clicker" href="new.html">New</a>
 <div id="foo"></div>
</main>
<script>
  $('.clicker').on('click', function (evt) {
    $("#foo").load("new.html");
    return false;
  });
</script>
```

new.html:

```
<div class="new">
  <p>I am new!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That was a part of the final solution, I had to have this click handler, but in another file (custom.js), where a function was executed at the loading and not when clicking on it. Thanks for the help !

The exact solution was from @CarstenLøvboAndersen in the comments of my main post.